# How to restore a database from a newer version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 and I want to restore a database from SQL Server 2008 R2. When I try to restore, SQL Server produces an error message that the database came from a newer version of SQL Server than the one I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but backup and restore won't allow you to restore that way - you can only restore to a higher version (backwards compatibility) rather than a lower version (forwards compatibility?). You'll need to export and import the data, or use scripts, or some other way of transferring everything.